# prefabs not aligned at same horizantal level after instantiating

Tags: unity, prefabs

I have generated a logical grid and trying to place a prefab on top of that grid.

`Piece` is the base class for all pieces

`Pieces[]` is the 2d array holding all the pieces

1. instantiate  and spawn prefab

```
private Piece spwanSinglePiece() {

 Piece cp = Instantiate(prefabs[0], transform, false).GetComponent<Piece>();
return cp
}
```

2. Position them

```
  private void PositionSinglePiece(int x, int y, bool force = false)
    {
      
        

        Pieces[x, y].transform.position = GetTileCenter(x, y);



    }
    private Vector3 GetTileCenter(int x, int y)
    {
        return  new Vector3(x * tileSize, (float)(yOffSet +0.85), y * tileSize) - bounds + new Vector3(tileSize/2,0,tileSize/2);
    }
```

Scenario

1. only yoffset value is helpful to place them on top of the board
2. but different prefab pieces require different yoffset value. cause after instantiating they are not on the same base
3. board scale is set to 1,1,1 so that parenting doesn't scale the pieces along with it
4. created prefabs scale is also 1.

Problem
prefabs are not exactly on the same horizontal alignment. which is resulting in the use of different yoffset values for each piece.

if all the pieces are aligned horizontally same they single yoffset value can work this what I am trying to achieve

[image]

More details

original prefabs transform

[image]

clone prefab generated after running script.
every clone prefab has a y transform of 1.05 after being generated. which is expected but all prefabs are not on same horizontal line.

so they are in different vertical position. I am not sure what really causing a issue

[image]

update - using primitive objects, scripts just run fine and produce expected results.

I think its a problem with the pieces that were created in the blender and exported into Unity

```
 1. after creating the mesh, rotating and scale applied 
 2. centred origin to geometry and pivot to the median point
 3. normals recalculated
 4. while exporting settings where as follows
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the objects we see in the screenshot all from the same prefab or are they different prefabs? Do those objects coming from the same prefab also have the same vertical offset?

Comment: all are different prefabs , made from different fbx files

Comment: updated question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the models were not properly aligned in the 3d modeling program used to create them.

The ideal solution would of course be to tell the art department to get back to their 3d modeling program and move the meshes within their model files so that the floor is on height 0. This is usually a standard convention for game-ready 3d assets which are designed to be placed on a horizontal surface.

But when you got the assets from a source you can't make demands to, then you can fix this in Unity.

Create each piece prefab as an empty game-object with the 3d model as a child. You can now edit the prefab and adjust the local position of the child transform relative to the parent transform so that the base is exactly on the 0:0:0 point of the parent.

Comment: How it can be achieved! I tried doing changing the location to 0,0,0 and then exported it. but no success.

Comment: @pavanjoshi914 I don't even know which 3d modeling program you are using, so I can't help you with that. But did you try the second thing I mentioned? Parenting the model in an empty game object, moving the model up within that object and then turning the whole thing into a prefab?

Comment: Actually, I made a pivot point to the centre but vertically it was at the centre mid and not at the base. correcting this made it work.

Your answer was really helpful for figuring this out , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetTileCenter()` seems to be taking the mid points (horizontal & vertical), but from the image, it looks like each of the prefab have different height, so even though their midpoint is alligned, because of height, it looks uneven.

For height, you can rather use the top position, `new Vector3(tileSize/2,0,0);`

Comment: Not working. in unity, y-direction is upward, so I took tilesize/2 only for x and z in the same plane. which is giving me the exact tile centre. 

using ```tilesize/2,0,0``` neither fixing the problem , also moving chess pieces away from the center of the tile

Comment: Sorry my bad, seemsl like your issue is with `(float)(yOffSet +0.85)`, since the pieces are not of same height, you can get the height of mesh and calculate the top/bottom to align or do as @Phillip to parent the prefabs to empty GameObject